# Do I have to change the $S_z$ eigenbasis to $S_x$ or $S_y$ eigenbasis to calculate statistical properties for $S_x$ or $S_y$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum

I'd like to know what the quantum average values $\langle S_x \rangle$ and $\langle S_x \rangle$ are given the initial state of a system in the $S_z$ eigenbasis $|\psi(0)\rangle = N|1\rangle + 2i|2\rangle$.

I've calculated the average value of $\langle S_z \rangle$ by using $\langle \psi(0) | S_z | \psi(0) \rangle$ where $S_z=\frac{\hbar}{2}|1\rangle\langle 1| - \frac{\hbar}{2} |2\rangle\langle 2|$, but I'm not sure if to calculate $\langle S_x \rangle$ and $\langle S_y \rangle$ I must change change the initial state $|\psi(0)\rangle = N|1\rangle + 2i|2\rangle$ from $S_z$ eigenbasis to the $S_x$ eigenbasis and later $S_y$ eigenbasis to calculate their probabilities, averages and uncertainty. I'd like some help, thanks.

Comment: I believe you miswrote the operator $S_z$. It should be a matrix, but you wrote it as if it was a vector. Furthermore, notice that the state you provided is not normalized.

Comment: what are $\vert 1\rangle$ and $\vert 2\rangle$?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to change the basis in order to make the calculation. You can do it directly in the $S_z$ basis, provided you write the expressions for $S_x$ and $S_y$ in the $S_z$ basis. They are given in terms of Pauli matrices by $S_i = \frac{\hbar}{2} \sigma_i$, for $i = x, y, z$. For example, $S_x$ is given by
$$S_x = \frac{\hbar}{2} \sigma_x = \frac{\hbar}{2} |1\rangle\langle 2| + \frac{\hbar}{2} |2\rangle\langle 1|.$$

Once that is done, you can compute the expectation values using $\langle S_i \rangle = \langle \psi | S_i | \psi \rangle$, exactly as you did for $S_z$.